# Подход к обработке исключений c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, исключения

Вопрос больше ориентирован на архитектурный подход или рефакторинг. Например есть консольное приложение, где есть класс FileWorker работающий с файлами , экземпляр которого инициализируется в Programm.cs в точке входа (main) и идет дальнейшая работа с его методами. Правильно ли для обработки исключений блок конструкцию try catch размещать только в точке входа main, как говорится прокидывать при исключениях ошибки вверх, или все же try catch нужно вешать непосредственно внутри методов и классов? Хочется избежать перенагромаждения синтаксиса кавычек и т.д. -прийти к лаконичности. И также хотелось бы узнать как элегантно обрабатывать исключения асинхронных методов (asynh await), как прокидывать из них throw до основного потока?

Comment: [Правила разработки исключений](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exceptions)

Comment: Холиварно и не во всём корректно, но неплохо описаны подходы: https://habr.com/en/company/vdsina/blog/523618/

Comment: связанные вопросы [Чем плох перехват всех исключений разом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/856798/179763), [Стоит ли обрабатывать исключения во вложенных методах, если в вызывающем методе есть try catch?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/820168/179763)

Comment: Приложение не должно падать. И глобальный `catch` конечно решит проблему, но поможет ли он вам чинить приложение? Как по мне, чем меньше кода обернуто в `try` - тем лучше, это значит, что во всех остальных местах вы не ожидаете исключений. С асинхронным кодом все так же как с синхронным. Если хотите, используйте общий обработчик - метод принимающий исключение как аргумент. Грубо говоря, чем ближе `catch` к месту выброса исключения, тем проще отлаживать. Это просто моё мнение.

Answer (score 4):

Не всегда и не все исключения надо пробрасывать "наверх". Например, вы работаете с каналами связи - качаете файл через сеть, или парсите сайт или ещё что-то такое делаете и у вас вышла ошибка - связь оборвалась/вышел таймаут/антивирус заблокировал файл на проверку. Хорошо ли в этом случае бросать исключение на самый верх в `main`? Конечно же нет! Есть ошибки, после которых вы должны поймать исключение примерно в том месте, где оно выбросилось (или чуть выше по коду - смотря как у вас сделан рефакторинг) и сделать что-то из следующего (а может и несколько пунктов сразу):

- Сделать паузу и попробовать выполнить последнюю операцию ещё раз (и так несколько раз в цикле)
- Положить обрабатываемый элемент обратно в очередь обработки (у вас же есть очередь обработки?), увеличив у этого элемента число совершённых попыток и пометив, когда была последняя попытка
- Отослать письмо на заранее прописанные адреса с текстом "Шеф, все пропало, гипс снимают, клиент уезжает!"
- Почистить место на диске, рестартовать сервис, перегрузить модем...

Действия эти должны делаться на соответствующем уровне программы. И таких примеров можно придумать много. Поэтому надо смотреть, где у вас есть цельная задача, которая должна выполняться одним блоком и перехватывать исключения так, чтобы можно было легко повторить этот блок действий по мере необходимости.

Но при этом обычно перехватывают исключения и в самом низу, где произошла проблема, хотя бы чтобы её залогировать там, где о ней можно собрать максимум информации - что за ошибка произошла, с какими параметрами в этот момент была вызвана функция и т.д. (какой файл и куда мы пытались передать или получить, например), а потом уже пробросить исключение выше.

Тонкостей много и универсальные советы давать сложно. Но в любом случае нужно учитывать много факторов и смотреть на дизайн программы, на её потоки исполнения, а не просто ловить исключения там, где вам кто-то сказал это делать.

И надо чётко осознавать дизайн своей программы - какие методы могут выбросить исключения, а какие нет, чтобы знать, когда и где лучше эти исключения поймать, а где этого делать не нужно, чтобы не тормозить выполнение программы и не загромождать код.

Answer (score 0):

Это все хорошо, но как сделать код более читаемым, если не прокидывать наверх Exceptions.
Хочется ,чтобы обработчик ошибок был один на клиентской вызывающей стороне (main) в точке входа, где инициализируются обьекты и идет работа с ними, не хочется под их капотом нагромождать блоки try catch , дабы избежать синтаксические громоходы-болячки в духе языка Flutter :) -где проблемы с символами "{}", делает код менее читаемым.

Comment: @Саша, перелогиньтесь, и это не ответ должен быть, а комментарий. Удалите этот ответ и оставьте комментарий там, где хотели.